# Regular Expression Help PHP for Valid JSON

Tags: php, regex

I am having one string which is not valid json.  i would like to convert that string to valid json. It is required double quote for valid json.

here is string

```
{
                $page: $('.js-profile'),
                id: 242144,
                docName: Mr. test,
                gender: test,
                testid: -1,
                testPlanId: -1,
                tesstspecialty: doctor,
                date: null,
                isPatientExisting: false,                
                constraints: {},
                culture: en,
                isMobile: false,
                isIE8: false,
                isLocked: false,
                isUserLoggedIn: false,
                startTime: 3/30/2018,
                dateFormatString: {0}-{1}-{2},
                searchUrl: /search?address=10003&dr_specialty=99&match_insurance=on,
                locationId: 87800,
                test : {
                test: 1, test:6
                }
            }
```

Can anybody help on to make reg expression that will add double quote into string?

Any kind of help appreciated .

Comment: It would be particularly helpful to post the expected output.

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful to you? Feel free to upvote and/or accept.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to do in one regex, but quite easy to convert the first part and then add quotes to the values:

```
<?php
$invalidJson = <<<json
{
                \$page: $('.js-profile'),
                id: 242144,
                docName: Mr. test,
                gender: test,
                testid: -1,
                testPlanId: -1,
                tesstspecialty: doctor,
                date: null,
                isPatientExisting: false,                
                constraints: {},
                culture: en,
                isMobile: false,
                isIE8: false,
                isLocked: false,
                isUserLoggedIn: false,
                startTime: 3/30/2018,
                dateFormatString: {0}-{1}-{2},
                searchUrl: /search?address=10003&dr_specialty=99&match_insurance=on,
                locationId: 87800,
                test : {
                test: 1, test:6
                }
            }
json;
$validJson = preg_replace("/([a-z0-9$]+)\s*:/i", '"$1":', $invalidJson); // Replace the first part
$validJson = str_replace("{}", "{\n}", $validJson); // Make sure {} will be treated as an empty array
$validJson = preg_replace("/:\s*([^,\n]+),/i", ': "$1",', $validJson); // Quote the values
var_dump(json_decode($validJson, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the hard route and tried to fix it in one go:

[This](https://regex101.com/r/SGFtfM/2) also leaves data types like `null` that do not need to be quoted as is:

`([\$\w]+)\s*: ?(?|(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4})|(\{[^{\n-]+\}-?\{[^{\n-]+\}-?\{[^{\n-]+\}-?)+|(?(?!null|false|true|-?\d+|{\s*})([^{\n,]*)))`

After a `preg_replace` with `"$1": "$2"` only unnecessary double quotes need to be removed:

```
<?php
$re = '/([\$\w]+)\s*: ?(?|(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4})|(\{[^{\n-]+\}-?\{[^{\n-]+\}-?\{[^{\n-]+\}-?)+|(?(?!null|false|true|-?\d+|{\s*})([^{\n,]*)))/m';
$str = '{
    $page: $(\'.js-profile\'),
    id: 242144,
    docName: Mr. test,
    gender: test,
    testid: -1,
    testPlanId: -1,
    tesstspecialty: doctor,
    date: null,
    isPatientExisting: false,                
    constraints: {},
    culture: en,
    isMobile: false,
    isIE8: false,
    isLocked: false,
    isUserLoggedIn: false,
    startTime: 3/30/2018,
    dateFormatString: {0}-{1}-{2},
    searchUrl: /search?address=10003&dr_specialty=99&match_insurance=on,
    locationId: 87800,
    test : {
    testa: 1, testb:6.4
    }
}';
$subst = '"$1": "$2"';    
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);    
echo str_replace('""', '', $result);
```

The result looks pretty good I would say:

```
{
    "$page": "$('.js-profile')",
    "id": 242144,
    "docName": "Mr. test",
    "gender": "test",
    "testid": -1,
    "testPlanId": -1,
    "tesstspecialty": "doctor",
    "date": null,
    "isPatientExisting": false,                
    "constraints": {},
    "culture": "en",
    "isMobile": false,
    "isIE8": false,
    "isLocked": false,
    "isUserLoggedIn": false,
    "startTime": "3/30/2018",
    "dateFormatString": "{0}-{1}-{2}",
    "searchUrl": "/search?address=10003&dr_specialty=99&match_insurance=on",
    "locationId": 87800,
    "test": {
    "testa": 1, "testb": 6.4
    }
}
```

Comment: However, this will not cover all possible digressions or if the file is too badly damaged.